# How can I set the variable type with an if/then statement in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sqldatareader

I have a function which performs an SQL query. Depending on a registry value, it will either hit SQL Server or SQL Server Compact Edition. If it is using SQL Server CE, the line setting the recordSet variable should read like this:

```
SqlCeDataReader recordSet = da.ExecuteSQLCommand(selectCommand);
```

For SQL Server, it should read like this:

```
SqlDataReader recordSet = da.ExecuteSQLCommand(selectCommand);
```

I am trying to put all this in an if/then statement at the beginning at the function but cannot seem to figure out how to set the Type within the if/then. Here is my (partial) code:

```
public static string SqlQuery(string selectCommand, int regval)
{
    var recordSet = null;
    string selectCommand = "select * from whatever";

    if (regval == 0)
    {
        SqlDataReader recordSet = null;
    }
    else
    {
        SqlCEDataReader recordSet = null;
    }

    recordSet = da.ExecuteSQLCommand(selectCommand);
}
```

The problem is that unless I declare the recordSet variable before the if/else, I cannot use it after. However, if I declare it before the if/else, I cannot change the type.

Comment: Do the classes have a common ancestor?

Comment: I can't see how you'd expect this to work. What's the type of `da`? You're calling the same method in both cases, so you should be able to just use the declared return type.

Comment: declare it as DbDataReader before the if

Comment: @LefterisE - I believe both are inherited from IDataReader. If I declare it as IDataReader first, what would I need to do to get to a more specific type, if that is even possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can't do that. Variables' types are really set in stone at compile time unless you use `dynamic`.

You could use the common interface `IDataReader`. Other standard ADO.NET clients such as for MySQL and SQLite implement this too.

*Edit*

Here is a sample

```
public static string SqlQuery(string selectCommand, int regval)
{
    IDataReader recordSet = null;
    string selectCommand = "select * from whatever";
    recordSet = da.ExecuteSQLCommand(selectCommand);
}
```

Comment: Suggest the author make the answer more emphatic and explain  polyMorphism.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Comment: So would I be able to accomplish what I am trying to do by using a dynamic type? Is there an example you could show me?